# Google Sheets Script not sticky

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, permissions

I am trying to create a custom function for a Google Sheet. to do this, I start from within the Sheet that I want to use the function, I then go to the menu `Tools|<>Script Editor`.

I then write a function. Name the file. And save it.

But, I can not use this function. Error #NAME?

Then if I close the Script Editor and open it again, it's like I have never been there. It presents the same form you see when you first start.

Comment: I have discovered the issue, but not the solution. 

When the script editor is opened it switches me to another Google account I have. So I  switch back. But then I am presented within a screen saying Acess Denied and making me ask permission. To whom and what for I am not sure.

Comment: You can try to change the default account.  Maybe it will help https://www.androidcentral.com/how-change-your-default-google-account.
You can also just sign out of other accounts.

Comment: Do you wanna share with us the function and also how you call it from the spreadsheet file? Also did you save the function in the script before you call it from the sheet?

Answer (score 0):

From an OP comment

> I have discovered the issue, but not the solution. When the script editor is opened it switches me to another Google account I have. So I switch back. But then I am presented within a screen saying Acess Denied and making me ask permission. To whom and what for I am not sure.

The solution to the root cause of the problem depends on Google, fortunately there are several workarounds.

1. Use Chrome in incognito mode with all the extensions disabled, then **sign in on only one account** (the key part is bold)
2. Use another web browser or web browser profile. **Sign in on only one account** (the key part is bold)
3. Signout of all your Google accounts, then sign in first on the account that you will be using for developing your scripts, then sign in on the other accounts. This still migth be problematic under certain circunstances.

Also, as good habit, when you click Tools > Open script editor to create a new bounded project, the first thing that you should do is give a name to your project.

Another god habit, before testing a custom function, be sure that there isn't a project file with a red asterisk (unsaved file). Contrary to spreadsheets, the Apps Script files aren't automacatily saved when a edit is made.